# Passing Variable to Find Element By Xpath

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to pass a variable to `find_element_by_xpath`.

When I use the following statement it works ok:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody/tr/td[contains(.,'searchtext')]/following::td[1]").text
```

But when I try to pass the search text as a variable like this I get an error:

```
myvariable = 'searchtext'
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody/tr/td[contains(.,'myvariable')]/following::td[1]").text
```

It's the same with this:

```
myvariable = 'searchtext'
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody/tr/td[contains(.,(myvariable)')]/following::td[1]").text
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the wrong parsing you've done. Use f-string, read more about [f-Strings: A New and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python](http://f-Strings:%20A%20New%20and%20Improved%20Way%20to%20Format%20Strings%20in%20Python)

so instead of

```
myvariable = 'searchtext'
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody/tr/td[contains(.,'myvariable')]/following::td[1]").text
```

do this :

```
myvariable = 'searchtext'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//tbody/tr/td[contains(.,'{myvariable}')]/following::td[1]").text
```

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the ***myvariable*** as a string, and not passing in the variable.

Instead use `.format` like this:

```
myvariable = 'searchtext'
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody/tr/td[contains(.,{})]/following::td[1]").text.format(myvariable)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fill the variable this way. Better use str.format :

```
myvariable = 'searchtext'
driver.find_element_by_xpath( str.format("//tbody/tr/td[contains(.,'{}')]/following::td[1]"),myvariable)).text
```

Other way is to concat strings :

```
myvariable = 'searchtext'
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody/tr/td[contains(.,' ”+myvariable+”’)]/following::td[1]").text
```